# Put app download button inside an app.

Tags: java, android

I know that people put app download buttons on websites. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to put one inside another app. The app I'm building only works with another app. So I want to put a download button for that app at the bottom of my first page. Is that particle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah that's possible, you can simply add an `ImageView` with the Playstore logo (or anything really) and then add something like this:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url = "<!LINK TO APP IN PLAYSTORE>";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!